# NexusDB: <unnamed TnxODBCQuery instance>: Query execution failed: Type mismatch (nxtInterval <> nxtNullString) when comparing at line

Tags: c#, nexusdb

Getting the error below, when I was trying to pull the records from Nexus Database.

**Error:**

> NexusDB: : Query execution failed: 
>       Type mismatch (nxtInterval <> nxtNullString) when comparing at [$3CA0/15520]

**Query:**

```
SELECT * from 
FROM Student
INNER JOIN Department on Department.Code =  Student.DepartmentCode AND (Department.INACTIVE = false OR Department.INACTIVE IS NULL) 
WHERE  Student.DepartmentCode in ?listofCode?
```

listofCode=> 'Mec,Ece'

Note: We are using Dapper

Answer (score 1):

Using a parameter for the IN ... list is not supported. Use literals, eg IN ('Mec', 'Ece')